# Apache Server File Query

Tags: apache

I have an Apache server that has multiple files located on it. Each file is an updated version from the previous file. Eg. release-2013-07-20 is an older file and release-2013-07-25 is the newer file.

I am looking to query the apache server and have an display of the most updated file via website link.

I am unsure how to go about accomplishing this and I am looking for some suggestions.

Comment: What language are you trying to use to query the server? What have you tried? Is this even a programming question? System administration questions should be posted at serverfault.com.

Comment: I didn't know about serverfault.com. I will post the question there. Thank you!

Comment: I can flag it for migration.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a unix server, the following command on the relevant directory will return the name of the file that was last modified (most updated):

```
ls -ltr | grep ^- | awk '{print $9}' | sed -n 1p
```

you can use this filename in order to copy or generate a link to it